# xnee compilation fails on cnee

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation

I am old xnee user.I am using xnee for desktop and
testing automation.My current linux desktop is Manjaro linux with last
updates.

I am trying to compile xnee from different sources such as
my AUR repo, ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/xnee/xnee-3.19.tar.gz and
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/xnee/.
But every time i fail with same error in same place.

First of all i am doing:
export LDFLAGS='-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition'

then i do ./configure && make

and every time compilation fail with error:

```
Generating texi file from: cnee
./cnee --texipage > cnee.texi
make[3]: *** [Makefile:814: cnee.texi] Error 139
```

This error happens because compiled cnee works rong.
I run gdb --args ./cnee --help and it segfaults with:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555d956 in xnee_parse_cnee_option
(xd=xd@entry=0x5555555942a0,
opt_and_args=opt_and_args@entry=0x7fffffffdc70,
args_used=args_used@entry=0x7fffffffdb04) at parse.c:379 379
key = cnee_options[entry].key;
```

i guess because pointer cnee_options has value
0x0 at runtime, instead of pointing to cnee_options_impl.

And it happens in every xnee distro source i use.
Pls can u help me with this!!
Thank you!!!!